# ssh2_connect() для xampp

Tags: php, php7, xampp

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function `ssh2_connect()` in ...

как установить для php  `7.1.15` и где взять нужные библиотеки?

стоит xampp win 7 32 bit

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/ssh2.installation.php ознакомились?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34920250/installing-ssh2-on-xampp  сдесь есть порядок, но с библиотеками засада какой версии качать